# Contraction Mapping and Fixed Point with two different distance metrics

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fixed-points, contraction-operator

I have been looking at the fixed point theorems that use the contraction-mapping and all seem to use the same distance metric for the input and output spaces. If we have a differentiable mapping $f: X \rightarrow X$. I was wondering if we could use different distance metrics for the input $X$ and output $X$, say $d'$ and $d$. If we have $d'(f(x),f(y))\le k d(x,y)$ with $0<k<1$, would we still have a fixed point for $f$? Will it be unique?

Comment: The whole idea of the fixed point theorem is that you can iterate the map, which requires the same structure in input and output.

Comment: I would still suggest to think about a more interesting case, when those mertics induce the same topology

Comment: @Ilya Would the conclusion change if the two metrics induce the same topology. For example if $d'$ and $d$ were the $sup$ and $l_{1}$ norms respectively.

Comment: Not sure, actually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X = [0,1]$, $d'$ be the usual Euclidean metric and $d$ be a
multiple of the discrete metric, that is $d(x,x') = 2$ unless $x = x'$. Is the map
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1,& \text{if }x< \frac12
\\
0,& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
contractive according to your definition?

Comment: Here, $f$ satisfies the distance-inequality I wrote in the question, but it does not have a fixed point. Thank you!